# Java shifting code and class objects to a remove server with a restricted interface

Tags: java, serialization, client-server, classloader

My problem is the following:

- I want to send code to a remote server using Java 6 on both ends.
- This codes uses classes that are not known to the server.
- My only interface to communicate with that server end is:

  byte [] invoke(byte[] request)

I can change the client and server end however I want. However I am restricted to this interface.
My client and server (as well as the interface and respective network connectivity) are up and running.

**Question** : What are my options to load the local classes (hopefully only using the .class object);  shift them to the remote end (and load them);  and finally to transfer a selectively piece of code to the server that will use them. All this in run time.

**Background**: I am doing a data store prototype. I want the clients to push methods to that data store that will manipulate one or more values inside the data store. The code pushed will be able to deserialize byte arrays into object values (unknown to the data store server). The interface is restricted by the middleware used to communicate with the data store but I  can not change it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you already have code on client and server side that establishes the network connection? Are you only stuck with the code transferring issue or in general?

Comment: Updated the question. Hope I made it more evident. I am stuck only with the code transferring issue.